# How to get the bounding box from an inference with en tensorrt model

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, tensorrt

I use YOLO-NAS model to perform real time object detection. I have exported the .pth to .onnx and then compiled it with tensorrt to get a .engine.

I would like to kmow if someone have a Python script which loads a .engine and gets the bounding boxes coordinates of the detected objects.

I saw on the following answer a script but I can't get the bounding boxes coordinate after the inference. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68241748/17690749)